If 2x+3y=117, what two values of x and y are closest together?
If 2x+3y=117, what two values of x and y are closest together? What is the min (|x-y|) if

both x and y are integers?
x and y can be any real number?



Part 2: x = y = 117/5 = 23.4.  Delta = 0


Part 1: Obviously from part 2, they must be 23 and 24. Since 117 is 2 more than a multiple of 5, the 24 needs to be in there twice. So x=24 and y=23. Delta = 1.

